# Why is my event not being seen in a viewmodel listening for it

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a multi-project wpf application using mvvm.  The application uses the entity framework to derive its data and the data model was built using Devart's Entity Developer with the individual entities all implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and Changing.

For one of the entities In the DataModel project I have created a partial class with a specific event;

```
Partial Public Class KeyNumber


    Public Event Dirty()


    Private Sub OnInvoiceNumberChanged()
        IsDirty = True
        RaiseEvent Dirty()
    End Sub
```

In a viewmodel in a separate project that references the KeyNumber class I have the following;

```
Public Class KeyNumberViewModel
Inherits ViewModelBase


Private _isDirty As Boolean
Private _keyNumbers As IList(Of KeyNumber)
Private ReadOnly _entities As EntityClientCache
Private WithEvents kn As KeyNumber


''' <summary>
''' Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="KeyNumberViewModel"/> class.
''' </summary>
Public Sub New(ByVal data As FtProContext)
    kn = New KeyNumber
    _entities = data.ClientCache
    _keyNumbers = data.KeyNumbersList
    DisplayName = "Key Numbers"
    'AddHandler kn.Dirty,AddressOf KeyNumberNotification

End Sub

Private Sub KeyNumberNotification() Handles kn.Dirty

    MessageBox.Show("Hi")
End Sub
```

I have placed a breakpoint in the KeyNumber class at the point at which the Dirty event is raised and whenever I change an invoive number in the View that has the KeyNumberViewModel as its datacontext it is being hit, yet for some reason my test message that I put in the viewmodel handler that is supposed to handle the Dirty event is never getting fired.

All the code compiles so ther's no clear error that I can work back from, which suggests that this is a more fundamental mistake on my part.

I'd welcome some pointers or explanations as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information, but your viewmodel has a `private` `KeyNumber` field. So how is it exposed to the view?

Comment: @Jon Yest there is a Private kn as KeyNumber which is then instatiated in the constructor of the viewmodel  below (which you can see ).  Given that I want the viewmodel to receive notification of the event from the keynumber class is this not the correct way to do this.  certainly all of the examples I've looked at seem to do it this way.  However I may well be wrong and that's what I would like to clarify.